# If cart is empty, the cart page will redirect to shop page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce, I want to redirect the cart page to shop page when the cart page is empty otherwise shows the cart page. Can anyone have the solution ?

Here is the code I have tried, but it does not work:

```
function my_empty_cart() {
  global $woocommerce;

    if (isset( $_GET['empty-cart'] ) ) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'product' ) ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_empty_cart' );
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`// old woocommerce :  use sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) to check cart content count`

`// In new woocommerce 2.1+ : WC()->cart->cart_contents_count to check cart content count`

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'redirection_function');
function redirection_function(){
    global $woocommerce;
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
    }
}
```

`init` hook will run everytime. use `template_redirect`

`==============Updates=============`

In new woocommerce, they have updated the functionality and now you can use following function to directly get the cart content count.

`WC()->cart->cart_contents_count`

Comment: `init` runs **everywhere**... I'd try with `template_redirect`.

Comment: yeah..you can check and redirect the user on the cart page itself.

Comment: I also placed this function in cart.php. Does not work

Comment: Have test these code from your end @Pushpak patel ?

Comment: yeah. i added the following code to my functions.php file and works fine. use `get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )` to redirect to shop page

Comment: can u please paste your code somewhere( Pastebin ), so I can have a look. Which file are you putting the code n what code exactly are u using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55899/discussion-between-user3518270-and-pushpak-patel).

Comment: they changed the variables. instead of `sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents )` you need to check for `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count`, what returns an integer (0 if empty)

Comment: thanks @honk31 for the reminder. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: It doesn't work when you have an item in the shopping cart and you remove it from the cart.

Comment: Thank you. This one is working.

Answer (score 8):

#### 2021 Update

Since WooCommerce version 3 use the following to redirect to shop page when trying to access cart page and cart is already empty:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart_redirect' );
function empty_cart_redirect(){
    if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Notes - Obsolete and deprecated code:**

- `global $woocommerce;` use with `$woocommerce->cart` is replaced simply by `WC()->cart`
- `sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) == 0` is replaced by simple `WC()->cart->is_empty()`
- `woocommerce_get_page_id()` is replaced by `wc_get_page_id()`

---

**When removing all cart items on cart page**, to make the redirection active, some additional jQuery code is required, see: [Redirect to shop if cart is emptied on cart page in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853947/on-cart-page-if-cart-is-emptied-redirect-to-shop-page-in-woocommerce-3/65855984#65855984)

Answer (score 5):

Just tested this myself as I needed something similar.

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_page('cart') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Pushpak's solution, but it doesn't work anymore. To check the cart content please use this code:

```
global $woocommerce;
if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count != 0 ) {
    // cart has content
} else {
    // cart is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2018 - 25 - Sept

working for me today::

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop() {
  global $woocommerce, $woocommerce_errors;

if ( is_cart() && sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) == 0) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); 
     exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

Comment: It seems as a very old question. Anyway its' good that you tried to answer which may help others. But try to answer for newer questions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to woocommerce folder and navigate to the CART folder.. in there is a cart-empty.php

then locate the following:

```
<p><a class="button1 btn btn-normal" href="<?php echo get_permalink.....
```

it would say getpermalink(woocommerce_.....

simply change that to

```
<p><a class="button1 btn btn-normal" href="<?php echo get_permalink('THE PAGE ID YOU WANT TO REDIRECT TO');
```

and bobs your uncle.. it will redirect to page with id you specify.

Let me know if you dont understand.

Comment: I recommend adding some code to your function.php file. When you update the plugin, you'll have to redo this...flip that.