# Redirect to shop if cart is emptied on cart page in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I want to redirect from cart to shop page when cart is empty and I am using this code:

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop(){
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_page('cart') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

This code works only if cart is empty and I try to go on cart page. But if I am already on cart page and I remove all cart items, I have to reload the page to get redirected. So I guess I have to add something in the code to reload the page. Any thoughts?

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is a bit obsolete since WooCommerce version 3. Now on cart page, PHP redirect is useless, because **Emptying cart** is an Ajax customer live event. So in this case Javascript (jQuery) is required.

Use the following instead, that handle all cases:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart_redirection' );
function empty_cart_redirection(){
    if( is_cart() ) :
    
    // Here set the Url redirection
    $url_redirection = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
    
    // When trying to access cart page if cart is already empty  
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        wp_safe_redirect( $url_redirection );
        exit();
    }
    
    // When emptying cart on cart page
    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery(function($){
        $(document.body).on( 'wc_cart_emptied', function(){
            if ( $( '.woocommerce-cart-form' ).length === 0 ) {
                $(window.location).attr('href', '" . $url_redirection . "');
                return;
            }
        });
    });" );
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works in all WooCommerce versions since version 3.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOU HELP!

Comment: When I try to replace `shop` with anything like `home` o `/` or even `./` nothing works. How do I customize this to redirect and GO HOME instead of shop? I also tried using page ID and that doesn't work either. please advise @LoicTheAztec and thanks for the share.

Comment: i replaced line #6 with `$url_redirection = home_url() ;` and now i can redirect to home page.